# Why $[ (K(\alpha))(\beta) : K(\alpha) ] \leq m$ when $m$ is the order of $\alpha$ over $K$, $\beta$ algebraic

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K \subseteq L$ a field extension. $\alpha , \beta \in L$ algebraic over $ K$.

Why does it follow that $[ (K(\alpha))(\beta) : K(\alpha) ] \leq m$

Where $m$ is the order of $\alpha$ over $K$.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, I tried proving this with the multiplicity property of field extensions but it didn't work out.

edit: I think it might be a typo and the order of the field extension should be $\leq$ than the order of $\beta$ over $K$, does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes, I think your typo correction is accurate.  Otherwise, you could just choose any algebraic number $\beta$ such that its minimal polynomial over $K$ is both of a degree greater than $m$ and the same as its minimal polynomial over $K(\alpha)$.

Comment: The order of $\beta$ does make more sense.  The reason is briefly that the minimal polynomial for $\beta$ over $K(\alpha)$ divides the minimal polynomial for $\beta$ over $K$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have guessed, this is just a typo: $m$ should be the order of $\beta$, not the order of $\alpha$.